# Python "See help(type(self)) for accurate signature."

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

I have seen the following statement in a number of docstrings when `help()`ing a class: "See `help(type(self))` for accurate signature."

Notably, it is in the `help()` for `scipy.stats.binom.__init__` and for `stockfish.Stockfish.__init__` at the very least.  I assume, therefore, that it is some sort of stock message.

In any case, I can't figure out what the heck it means.  Is this useful information?  Note that, being "outside" of the class, so to speak, I never have access to `self`.  Furthermore, it is impossible to instantiate a class if I cannot access the signature of the `__init__` method, and can therefore not even do `help(type(my_object_instantiated))`.  Its a catch 22.  In order to use `__init__`, I need the signature for `__init__`, but in order to read the signature for `__init__`, I need to instantiate an object with `__init__`.  This point is strictly academic however, for even when I do manage to instantiate a `scipy.stats.binom`, it actually returns an object of an entirely *different* class, `rv_frozen`, with the exact same message in its `__init__` docstring, but whose signature is entirely different and entirely less useful.  In other words, `help(type(self))` actually does not give an accurate signature.  It is useless.

Does anyone know where this message comes from, or what I'm supposed to make of it?  Is it just stock rubbish from a documentation generator, or am I user-erroring?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate an object, you just need to know its class, so you can write `help(scipy.stats.binom)`

Comment: @Barmar, that is precisely the call to `help` that gives the cryptic docstring “See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.” (under the `__init__` method)

Comment: I found `See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.` here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/idle_test/test_calltip.py#L71. This looks like test code for IDLE. I cannot explain how that string ends up in docstrings in various libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a convention that the signature for constructing a class instance is put in the `__doc__` on the *class* (since that is what the user calls) rather than on `__init__` (or `__new__`) which determines that signature.  This is especially true for extension types (written in C) whose `__init__` cannot have its signature discovered via introspection.

The message that you see is part of the `type` class (see `help(type.__init__)`) and is thus inherited by metaclasses by default.

In some versions, `scipy.stats.binom` confuses the matter by not actually being a type; it is merely an instance of another class that (like `type`) is callable.  So asking for `help` on it merely gives the help for *that* class (just like `help(1)` gets you `help(int)`)—you have to look at its `__call__` for further information (if any).  And asking for `help` on the result of *calling* it gives you help for the actual class of whatever it returns, as you observed.